# <input> element does not post data?

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I have a form page and when I submit this form all inputs are posting successfully except this one:

```
<input id="TC" class="form-control" name="kullanici_id" type="text" onchange="edit()" 
  <?php if($this->data['kullanici_id']){echo 'readonly';} ?>  
  value="<?php echo $this->data['kullanici_id']?>">
```

But why?

-This is my .phtml file:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/admin/kaydet" method="post" onSubmit="javascript: beforeSubmit();">
    <?php if(strlen($this->data['id'])):?>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $this->data['id']?>">
    <?php endif;?>
    <font color="green"><h3>DÜZENLE</h3></font>
    <img src="/foto/<?php echo $this->data['fotograf']?>" height="110" width="110" align="left" />
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>T.C. Kimlik No.:</td>
            <td><input id="TC" class="form-control" name="kullanici_id" type="text" onchange="edit()" <?php if($this->data['kullanici_id']){echo 'readonly';} ?>  value="<?php echo $this->data['kullanici_id']?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <?php if(!strlen($this->data['id'])):?>
        <tr>
            <td>Parola:</td>
            <td><input id="password2" class="form-control" type="password" name="parola" value="<?php echo $this->data['parola']?>"></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Parola Tekrar:</td>
                <td><input onchange="passwordCheck(this.value)" class="form-control" type="password" name="parola" value="<?php echo $this->data['parola']?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk">KAYDET</button> </td>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I have an id; page looks like an edit member page, if I haven't; page will add a new member. In id="TC" input, if I edit a member, this input shouldn't change, so I add a readonly to solve this. But when I submit, input does not post.
Sorry about my bad English :D

Comment: Seems like the field is being set to `readonly`, so any changes are discarded and posted to the server. You might want to show us what the actual post looks like.

Comment: please post a full source code.

Comment: @IsaacKleinman since there is `readonly` not `disabled` in the given code. So it will definitely be processed

Comment: Does your input contain value or is it empty? I mean when you are looking in the form if you see some value :-) And also are you trying to var_dump() the whole post?

Comment: is the input inside your `<form>`?

Comment: You embedded html into a php class? Where does the `$this` comes from?

Comment: I add a full html file. I think its help for you :)

Comment: Guys I solved the problem. 
In .phtml file everything are true but in my php file, I accidently (:D) unset the post['kullanici_id'] , so I didn't reach this value. 
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Reason your field is not being submitted it is because its set to `readonly`.

Reason for this is 'If user cannot change the field there is no point of submitting it as value will always remain the same'.

One way to mitigate this behavior is to add hidden field with same name

```
<input type="hidden" name="kullanici_id" value="<?php echo $this->data['kullanici_id']?>"> />
<input id="TC" class="form-control" name="kullanici_id" type="text" onchange="edit()" <?php if($this->data['kullanici_id']){echo 'readonly';} ?>   value="<?php echo $this->data['kullanici_id']?>" />
```